# I want to jump into different classes with the user given input

Tags: android, class, text

I want to jump into a class with the user giving the input in numbers.
I have tried this:

```
EditText eTinput;
 int n;
n=eTinput.getText().toString;


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Class ourClass    =Class.forName("com.dvdroid.kannadavachanagalu.Shareb",+n);
        Intent ourintent = new Intent(BasavaSelect.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourintent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

But I am getting some errors as 'change input n to editable' and 'remove argument to match forname'

Can anybody help how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    EditText eTinput;
    eTinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEdittextIdFromXml);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        if(n==urvaluetocheck)
{

        Intent ourintent = new Intent(BasavaSelect.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourintent);

}

else if(n==urvaluetocheck)
{

        Intent ourintent = new Intent(BasavaSelect.this, classuwant);
        startActivity(ourintent);
}
..........

else
{

        Intent ourintent = new Intent(BasavaSelect.this, defaultclass);
        startActivity(ourintent);
}

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: My question is to use the inputted value to jump to the particular class not how to get input from the edittext.

Comment: be clear and specific what do u want to implement exactly so that others can understand... explain in brief...

Comment: i want to open different classes for different inputted values

Comment: I used switch statements instead!

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
EditText eTinput;
 int n;
n=eTinput.getText().toString;


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Class ourClass=Class.forName("com.dvdroid.kannadavachanagalu.Shareb");//Change this line
        Intent ourintent = new Intent(BasavaSelect.this, ourClass);
         ourintent.putExtra("Value", n); 
        startActivity(ourintent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
eTinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEdittextIdFromXml);
```